# How do I get Ubuntu to connect to my Android tablet?

Tags: 11.10, usb, android, mtp

What I'm doing is trying to run a software called gMTP, which is apparently what I need to do to transfer files back and forth to my Android Galaxy 10.1 Tab device.

I've [asked about it on the Android SE site](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/21730/5892), but it seems the problem might be on the Ubuntu side. I followed [these instructions](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=13755464&postcount=1) to get Ubuntu to support MTP.

However, when I run the software, I get "LIBMTP PANIC" and other errors.

```
$ gmtp
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung GT-P7510/Galaxy Tab 10.1.
PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt
Detect: Unable to open raw device?
LIBMTP PANIC: Trying to dump the error stack of a NULL device!
LIBMTP PANIC: Trying to clear the error stack of a NULL device!
```

It seems that the problem is on the Ubuntu side, so is there something I can do to fix it?

Comment: http://ubuntu.5.n6.nabble.com/Mounting-Android-Tablet-td4355762.html

Comment: You could also try apps such as Wifi explorer, or an FTP client, There's a File explorer available in the Plays tore that allows you to access your phone via FTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution turned out to be to upgrade to ICS. Now USB seems to work without any special drivers and as long as the Tablet USB connection settings are set to "Camera (PTP)" mode.

Answer (score 1):

MTP is unfortunately problematic on Linux. With the latest libmtp, Galaxy Tab 10.1 is correctly recognized, however you still may not be able to transfer files reliably.